# Fedora - systemd-resolved

Tags: fedora, bind, systemd-resolved

I'm an old school linux guy, and I will say I'm not a fan of systemd, but I'm trying to evolve because it's here to stay.  Network management is killing me.

My goal is simple.  I don't need a caching resolver on this server. I simply need resolve.conf it to point to the local IP which is running bind9.

How can I make my resolv.conf look like:

```
search ecaiken.com
nameserver 172.16.10.189
nameserver 172.16.10.12
```

... and survive reboots and system updates?  I'd like to disable the caching resolver to never start again.  I've read everyone's post on how to disable systemd-resolved, which isn't the right path.  I've tried creating stub files with DNSStubListener=no.  I can't seem to get systemd to stop trying to help me.

Since I'm running bind9 on this server the local caching resolver is causing problems for the local machine.

Comment: What happens when you [disable systemd-resolved](https://serverfault.com/questions/1060041/systemd-resolve-fails-to-resolve-hostnames-when-using-bind9)?  I.e, why is it not the "right path?"

Comment: OT : You know that you can still stay with good old openrc with gentoo or equivs.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/my.conf

[Resolve]
DNS=172.16.10.189
Cache=no
# Never fallback
FallbackDNS=
Domains=ecaiken.com
```

Comment: Thx.  Two points.  1). I understand that etc/systemd is under selinux control.  2). How do I tell resolvectl to use my.conf

Comment: 1) Doesn't matter 2) All the `*.conf` files in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/` are used by default. You'll have just to restart it to make it use the conf file.